# What is the probability....

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Anna writes down a random sequence created by the following process. She repeatedly rolls a fair
6-sided die. If the number she rolls is larger than all of the numbers she has previously rolled (if
any), then she writes the new number down and then continues rolling. Otherwise, she does not
write the new number down and the process ends.

Let X be the length of Anna’s sequence, and Y be the last number in her sequence.

For example, if Anna rolled 1 then 4 then 5 then 4, her sequence would be 1,4,5 and the random
variables X, Y would take values X = 3 and Y = 5.

---

**Question**

i) What is $P(X \le 2 \land Y = 4)$?

ii) What is $P(X\le4 \lor Y=6)$?

---

For i) my method was

since the length of the sequence is less than or equal to 2 AND the final number of the sequence has to be 4.

1. first roll is 4: $\frac{1}{6}$
2. second roll is 4: $\frac{3}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}$

Then I add them up.

For ii) I am not so sure how to solve it.

I found the probability of $P(Y=6) \approx 0.36$

But I don't know what to do next. I am also worried that my logic for part (i) is not correct.

---

This is a follow-up to the question that I asked yesterday on this site.

Comment: Part 1 is correct. For part 2 use $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Part (1) is wrong, since you didn’t ensure that it ends at $4.$ The next roll could be $5$ or $6.$

Comment: Given any subset of size $n\leq 4$ of $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$ which contains $6,$ there is a sequence of $n$ rolls corresponding to the subset. Also, if a six is rolled, it is always the end of the sequence. So for (2) the probability is: $$\sum_{n=1}^4\binom{5}{n-1}\frac1{6^n}$$

Comment: More generally, $$P(X=a,Y=b)=\frac{\binom{b-1}{a-1}}{6^a}\cdot\frac{b}{6}$$  for $1\leq b\leq 6.$

Comment: $$P(Y=b)=\frac {b7^{b-1}}{6^{b+1}}$$